# Removing the first lines of an ascii file as a python script tool

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, ascii

I want to delete the header of an ASCII file with a python script in ArcGIS. The header is always six lines long. 
After running the script that needs this ASCII file, I need to reinsert the header. The header is always the same text.
At the end it will be part of a Python-script-tool for the ArcGIS Modelbuilder.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: So you would need to rewrite the file twice. If the data part of the ASCII file isn't changing, just copy the data part to a new file, then delete it when done.